# Prevent local users from accessing uploads folder

Tags: php, file-upload

In my code for uploading pdf documents to my web-server, I have used move_uploaded_file.

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_source, $destin)
```

However, this command does not work unless I give 777 access to the uploads folder. I tried making it 775, but it wouldn't work.

I get the following error message

```
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/http/host1/public_html/internal/upload.php on line 82
```

By putting the uploads folder above public_html, I can prevent people from accessing them via a browser, but how do I prevent local users from accessing this folder through ssh?

Comment: `775` or `755` permissions should work if you set the owner or group of the uploads folder to `www-data`.

Comment: @Barmar There is no such user on my machine. It is an Arch installation.

Comment: Use whatever username runs the webserver.

Comment: @Barmar I did that, but it did not help.

Comment: Maybe ask on ServerFault, then, where you're more likely to find server administrastors who know the proper way to configure Arch. I can't even find a tag for it here.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some answers related to this question had suggested using

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

to find out the user to who the upload folder should be given appropriate permissions 0755. This information did not work for me.

However, the correct information was available in `phpinfo()` under the `apache2handler` header. It was `http`.

Among other things, I have restricted file types to pdf, set .htaccess to restrict cgi and also kept the uploads folder outside public_html to prevent access through browser.

I am not aware of further security concerns.